# Can a deployed JBoss web application simply disappear?

Tags: deployment, web-applications, jboss, jar

A strange problem occurred yesterday on a production system which has been running fine for weeks on a JBoss 4.2.3 application server: the JAR file containing the web application was no longer in the deployment folder (so the clients could no longer access the application). The server is running on a Windows box.

There was no indication of undeployment in the server logs. Normally JBoss detects if somebody deletes (or moves) a deployed web application file and executes the standard undeployment procedure, so there would be a log entry in this case.

Other web applications on the same system continued to run fine, so it was only this JAR file which simply disappeared.

Has somebody seen a similar problem with web applications on JBoss?

Comment: I don't know of any such behaviour in JBoss, something else must be afoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet my shoes that's not possible to happen spontaneously.

Check your security settings - didn't you leave JMX console accessible? Etc.